# How many concurrent client connections does Azure SignalR allow for free tier?

Tags: azure, signalr, azureportal

I was wondering how many CLIENTS you can have on at once. Not servers. I know based on their [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/signalr-service/) that you can have 20 concurrent server connections for free tier but was wondering if server somehow also meant clients.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really handy Azure Service Limits page that lists just about every service. You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-signalr-service-limits). Max connections per service unit per day in the Free tier is 20. Maximum service units for the Free tier is 5. So within the 24 hour period, you can have a max of 100 different clients connect.

Comment: I think your last question got cut off.